# Date query to select 1st to 3rd of current month and compare against a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-functions

I have an azure function that runs and executes commands spread out between the 1st-3rd of every month. I have a column 'datecolumn', that updates with the time each row was affected.

All rows have datecolumns that spans from the 1st to 3rd of every month,I want to check if this date is less than 1st-3rd the **current month** to make sure that each row is affected only once every month.

Let's say it's Jan 3 2020, I want the query to look and through all the rows and ignore those who already have been altered this month, ie datecolumn is showing 1st or 2nd of Jan 2020, and only select those who where altered and has a datecolumn value of sometime last month (dec 2019).

Expected result: date with  1st-3rd of current month.

I have tried with some code but I get get the days right but it selects every year.

Thanks

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME=CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '1/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) -- mm/dd/yyyy
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME=CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '3/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)  -- mm/dd/yyyy

;WITH Calender AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @endDate
)
 SELECT * FROM thetable where datecolumn BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take an other solution

```
SELECT whatever 
FROM thetable 
WHERE NOT (YEAR(datecolumn) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
      AND MONTH(datecolumn) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
      AND DAY(datecolumn) < 4)
```

Comment: Hi and thank you. But this returns rows that were affected on 1-3 of august 2019. It shouldnt return any rows where datecolumn is  1,2 or 3rd of (current month)august.

Comment: show all dates in august then except 1-3 or all row which are not in 1-3 of august (other month and year also)?

Comment: Show all dates that are not 1-3 of the current month(so now august, soon september, yea, other months and years). Thank you

Comment: Its not showing any month where date is 1-3 now, it should show July and other months not just august. Thanks again